# Regex to terminate on character or end of line

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have this (C#):

```
http:\/\/([^""']*[^""']*).*?((?=<)|(?=$))
```

As you can see i'm trying to use the lookahead to terminate the regex on `<` or end of line.
The above is not working :( If i remove the `|(?=$)` then it will only work if `<` is in the string. How can I get the regex to terminate when either `<` or `$` happens? (Note: I don't want to include the `<` in my result)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe your goal?  Are you trying to find urls that are either at the end of the line or followed by the '<' character?

Comment: Are you using SingleLine or Multiline as options?

Comment: @Gus To find any url starting with http:// but some urls include html elements (don't ask me why, I don't know), I want to make sure to exit before the `<` so it won't open a new tag and url will be still valid.

@OmegaMan Multiline and IgnoreCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `<` symbol to the character class also or otherwise the capturing group greedily captures the `<` character also.

```
http:\/\/([^"'<]*[^"'<]*).*?(?=<|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO6mC0/2)

This `[^"'<]*[^"'<]*` would be written as `[^"'<]*`,

```
@"http:\/\/([^""'<]*).*?(?=<|$)"
```

If the original string  has multiple lines then don't forget to include `\n` inside the character class. And it's better to include multiline modifier.

```
@"(?m)http:\/\/([^""'<\n]*).*?(?=<|$)"
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the regex to terminate when either < or $

You can use this lookahead with alternation:

```
(?=<|$)
```

Comment: I used `http:\/\/([^""']*[^""']*).*?(?=<|$)` and now it won't terminate on `<`.

Comment: Can you tell me your input string

Comment: `http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingCachedScripts//ReportPage_2_8_2_0.html?ebReportURL=http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&Page<script` as an example.

Comment: Actually correct regex would be `http://([^"']*?).*?(?=<|$)` as you can [see in this demo](http://regex101.com/r/fN9kI9/1)