# Extract substring from character A to character B or EOL using Regexp_extract of Big Query / Google Analytics

Tags: sql, regex, perl, google-analytics

I'm working with Google Big Query and try to extract some information from a string column into another column using Regexp_extract. In short:

Data in *myVariable*:

```
yippie/eggs-spam/?portlet:hungry=1234
yippie/eggs-spam/?portlet:hungry=456&portlet:hungrier=7890
```

I want a column with:

```
1234
456
```

My command:

```
SELECT Regexp_extract(myVariable, r'SOME_MAGIC') as result
FROM table
```

I tried for SOME_MAGIC:

```
hungry=(.*)[&$] - null, 456 (I learned that $ is interpreted as is)
hungry=(.*)(&|$) - Error: Exactly one capturing group must be specified
hungry=(.*)^& - null, null
hungry=(&.*)?$ - null, null
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333484/extracting-data-using-regexp-extract-in-google-bigquery), but there the number has a fixed length. Also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737128/regex-to-terminate-on-character-or-end-of-line), but "?=" is no known command for perl.

Does anybody have an idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer to how I can solve my problem differently:

```
hungry=([0-9]+) - 1234, 456
```

It isn't an answer to my abstract question (regex for selecting Charater A to [Character B or EOL]), so it's not that satisfying. E.g. it won't work with

```
yippie/eggs-spam/?portlet:hungry=12AB34
```

However my original problem is solved. I leave the question open for a while in case somebody has a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had a similar problem were I was trying to select the last 6 characters in a string (link_id) as a new column.

I kept getting this error:

> Exactly one capturing group must be specified

My code originally was:

```
SELECT
...
REGEXP_EXTRACT(link_id, r'......$') AS updated_link_id
FROM sometable;
```

To get rid of the error and retrieve the correct substring as a column, I had to add parentheses around my regex string.

```
SELECT
...
REGEXP_EXTRACT(link_id, r'(......$)') AS updated_link_id
FROM sometable;
```